# Illegal String offset & Trying to get property of non-object (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

So i've problem to print the result in blade that the data are from controller, so  :

1. UseController.php :

   ```
        $expertCategory = Category::getCategoryByID($user_id);
        $data = [ 'expertCategory' => $expertCategory ];
        return view('cms.user.edit', $data);
   ```
2. Category.php (models) getCategoryByID($user_id) return result array if i dd(expertCategory); in controller, which the result is :

   ```
   array:9 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "Beauty"
      "sequence" => 1
      "background_color" => "ffffff"
      "status" => "Active"
      "created_at" => "2017-06-19 09:41:38"
      "updated_at" => "2017-06-19 09:41:38"
      "icon_filename" => "beauty-icon"
      "iconURL" => array:3 [▼
               "small" => "http://localhost:8000/images/category_icons/small/beauty-icon"
              "medium" => "http://localhost:8000/images/category_icons/medium/beauty-icon"
        ]
   ]
   ```
3. But when i want to print using foreach the result in blade.php with code :

   ```
    @foreach($expertCategory as $expertCat)
      {{ $expertCat->id }}
    @endforeach
   ```

will return error "Trying to get property of non-object "

if i use code like this :

`@foreach($expertCategory as $expertCat)
  {{ $expertCat['id'] }}
 @endforeach`

it will return : "Illegal string offset 'id'"

anybody can help solve this problem :s ? many thanks !

Comment: Don't do a foreach, it's just `$expertCategory["id"]`. It is a single category you are getting after all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: thank you sir, thats really work, and just realize that my query use "first()" thats why when using for each will get error. thank you for ur help ! god bless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `$expertCategory` is a one `dimensional array` you are facing this issue

Just Replace this

```
$expertCategory = Category::getCategoryByID($user_id);
$data = [ 'expertCategory' => $expertCategory ];
return view('cms.user.edit', $data);
```

With

```
$expertCategory = Category::getCategoryByID($user_id);
$data = [ 'expertCategory' => [$expertCategory] ];
return view('cms.user.edit', $data);
```

Then use

```
@foreach($expertCategory as $expertCat)
  {{ $expertCat['id'] }}
@endforeach
```

In your blade it will work for you.

Comment: thank you sir Sahoo, just realize that my query select with "first()" only thats why i can't use for each . thank you for ur help sir !

Comment: @Axel you are welcome if your issue solved then just close your question by accepting my answer.Thank you :)